# How to have a set of combination as a condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I'm working on an integration project and have created a batchlog table where I store which combinations have been exported already and then check new data against that batchlog table. It worked pretty well as long as I mostly just stored one ID in batchlog table, let's say Customer ID and then selected new rows from Customer table like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE CusId NOT IN (SELECT CusID FROM IntegrationBatchlog)
```

However, now the solution is more complex and same row from Customer table will be exported several times in combination with other data so now I have couple of separate stored procedures and more columns in IntegrationBatchlog table (CusID, OrdertypeID and PaymentMethod) and join clauses in my select so now it's more like.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer c
JOIN....
JOIN...
JOIN...
WHERE there is not a row with that CusID AND OrderTypeID AND PaymentMethod in batchlog table yet.
```

So here I should check whether or not this exact combination has already been exported but how do you do that when you have like three several ID columns in batchlog table and you want to exclude those rows where all the three ID's are already present in same row in batchlog table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to do a `LEFT JOIN` to the IntegrationBatchLog table and only insert rows that aren't present.

```
select *
from Customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN IntegrationBatchLog i
  on c.CusId = i.CusId 
     and c.OrderTypeID = i.OrderTypeID 
     and c.PaymentMethod = i.PaymentMethod
where
  i.CusId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`, not `IN`. This allows multiple column matching

This is standard SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Customer c
JOIN....
JOIN...
JOIN...
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM IntegrationBatchlog I 
                WHERE C.CusID = I.CusID
                             AND C.OrderTypeID = I.OrderTypeID
                             AND C.PaymentMethod = I.PaymentMethod)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
FROM Customer c JOIN ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM IntegrationBatchLog I 
                  WHERE I.CusID = c.CusId AND 
                        I.OrderTypeId = c.OrderTypeID ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe NOT EXISTS would work here.  Here's an example from the MySQL docs (I don't know your DB) - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

The second example:

"What kind of store is present in no cities?"

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_type FROM stores
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cities_stores
                    WHERE cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type);
```

Maybe yours could be:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer c
JOIN....
JOIN...
JOIN...
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * FROM batchlog WHERE 
        c.CusID = batchlog.CusID AND 
        c.OrderTypeID = batchlog.OrderTypeID AND 
        c.PaymentMethod = batchlog.PaymentMethod
)
```